# iOS, iPhone - Popup image viewer

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview

I am looking for a way to duplicate the image pop up that the USAToday app and others have created (an image, sometimes with text, and a close X)?

**steve**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen those apps... But my guess is that you just use a UIView ... and add it as subview to whatever the current view you want the subview to show up (popup)/

Comment: Excellent!  Add a pinch of animation and wall...  Don't know why I hadn't thought of that...

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom UIViewController and read up on popovers.  Its very straight forward.

If you are on an iPhone just add a new custom subview.

Answer (score 0):

It's like any other UIViewController. Implement a delegate (see Utility template), and that's it.

Comment: I don't think I can get the same effect by pushing a view controller.  I could be wrong but the pop up (over) is a different.  The controller/view beneath is still visible.